# Blackscreen after boot

Tags: boot, asus

Casual Linux user here. Every time I boot up my laptop I can see the Ubuntu logo but then I get a black screen. I searched for some workarounds but they couldn't help, because I can't get into this special mode after pressing shift.

Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Comment: Do you have NVIDIA graphics?

Comment: Yes I have nvidia graphics

Answer (score 0):

In order to get to "this special mode," you basically have to spam the left shift key just as the POST finishes.

Once in recovery mode, try using the "fail-safe graphics mode." If you can get to the desktop, see if there are proprietary drivers available for your GPU. (Dash > Additional Drivers)

Comment: i cant make it into this mene, ive tried spamming shift at any possible point. Ideas?